# Can I mirror my Chrome browser to multiple Chromecast devices

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

We have a dashboard system (Dashing) that we can view through a browser (Chrome).  We have two TVs up displaying this dashboard now.  Each TV has a $350 PC connected to it.  I am wondering if we could use a Chromecast plugged into each TV and have only one PC "displaying" the dashboard.  This is relevant because 1) we are looking at adding monitors after we expand our office and 2) the PCs tend to be a pain in the ..., with things like updates pushed from IT, password chances, etc.  One PC would definitely be better.  Bonus points if I can get rid of all the PCs and just use Chromecast pointed at a URL.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you can only be connected to a single device at a time, hence can only mirror to one Cast device. You mentioned you are mirroring your browser. Is the content that you are mirroring a simple page, a video, ...? You may be able to come up with a simple app that would eliminate the need for having PC's completely. Tell us more about the content you are mirroring (hopefully it is not flash :-) )

Comment: It is definitely not flash. Dashing is all HTML5, and an example can be seen here: http://dashingdemo.herokuapp.com/sampletv

Comment: If it is a simple page that doesn't need any interaction (in terms of navigation, clicks, etc), then it is pretty straightforward to write a simple app that can cast that to Chromecast and once you do that, you need absolutely no PC, all you need is a phone or tablet to do the casting (and not a dedicated device, just cast it in the morning and let it runs for hours)

Comment: The answer is disappointing, but what I expected.  I guess I could look into creating an "App" for Chromecast, but honestly I have spent more time on making this work than I had hoped.  The thought of learning another stack that I will likely never use again is not particularly appealing. :-)

Comment: There are apps for Chromecast that I believe can help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

Although not supported officially, I was successfully able to cast my entire screen to two devices by using both the Google cast and the Google cast (Beta) extensions simultaneously. I could only get it to work using one extension in an incognito window and the other in a normal window.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast to multiple Cast devices if you create an additional "people" in Chrome settings for each of your Cast devices, then open a new window(not tab) for each "people".

Each "people"/user can attach to a different Cast device.  It helps to match the user name to the device or location to keep it all straight.

Ex: Cast a movie from NAS to 3 TVs.
    Use VLC to stream movie.
    Open 3 Chrome/chromium windows(not tabs), changing each window to a unique user/person.
    Start streaming.
    Point each window at stream, play and cast to a different device.

Performance will depend on ability of PC and router/wifi. We use the Ethernet power supply for Chromecast to reduce load on wifi AP. (We had Cat5 Ethernet already installed)

Since all browser windows are pointed at same stream, the sync is pretty good. Although we usually stream to living room, patio, and game room which a difference hard to detect.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome browser extension can only cast to one device.  A workaround is to install the Chrome browser extension Beta version alongside the non-beta version, and you'll have a second browser extension that can cast to a second device.

My colleague suggests that if you install Chrome Canary, the Beta version of Chrome, you can run two Chromes, with two extensions each, and support four devices.

Hopefully, this limitation will be removed, and the browser extension will support multiple devices.

Our use case is driving information kiosk displays from a single computer.  Chromecast is nice in that the display's physical security does not expose the PC driving the display.